# When ffmpeg creates an error what does hex in [h264 @ hex ] ... represent?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying to get a better understanding the error messages while doing stream/video analysis with ffmpeg, however I cannot find a document that goes over ffmpeg error message structure.

For example, when I get an error [h264 @ 0x3dea000] what does the 0x3dea000  hex represent?

Is that the frame reference, key or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the memory address of the h264 decoder, and is useful during debug. All the errors messages are printed afterwards.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, and is there a reference document that goes over error messages?

Comment: Not really. Some errors are user-addressable, but errors issued by a decoder or parser usually point to an corrupt or non-standard input.